# How to Make a image repeat in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I want to make a wall with a image repeating across it like wallpaper.

I tried it in the node editor but the image is taking up the entire plane. I just want it to be small and for the image to repeat across the entire plane.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 20):

All you need to do to get an image to repeat in a Cycles material is add a *Vector > Mapping* node between the *Texture Coordinates* and *Image Texture*.  Set the *Mapping* node to *Texture* at the top and set any of the *Scale:* values to less than one to make the image repeat along a certain (or multiple) axis(axes).

[image: Mapping node]

The other option, without adding any other nodes, is to simply scale up the UVmap in the *UV/Image Editor*. A UV map larger then the image will make the image repeat.

Comment: @BinaryGreen If this answer is acceptable, please consider to set it as the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to David's answer:

Note that to control how many times you want to repeat an image in a texture you can use the **Min** and **Max** values of the mapping node. Min 0 Max 1 will show the image one time only.

[image]