# Is there a way to tile a texture automatically over an object?

Tags: texturing, uv

There must be a simple option to tile a texture evenly over any object automatically. Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: sorry - my mistake won't do it again! It's because I was hoping there was a more uniform method to tiling textures on objects that may become more complex than a cube.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21175/how-to-make-a-image-repeat-in-cycles/21178#21178

Comment: Could you show an example of exactly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Cycles nodes, Box Projection is available, (maybe this can be done with Blender Internal as well, I'm not sure).

Here's the node setup.  The ***Blend*** slider works well for low frequency detail but tends to blur high-frequency detail.

[image]

If the model has UV Coordinates, you can bake the results for use with other applications.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I've been trying to achieve this for ages!

Answer (score 9):

While it isn't entirely clear what you are asking, if my assumption is correct, you want to map a texture onto an object in a way that it repeats X amount of times over one or both axes. Like a tiled floor.

The easiest way to do this is to scale the UV coordinates in the image editor to X times the bounds of the UV space. Any faces assigned UVs outside of this space will loop or "tile" like so:

Before scaling
[image: before scaling UVs]

After scaling
[image: after scaling UVs]