# Take 1 seamless textured plane, and make a large square out of multiple of that 1 texture

Tags: texturing

I have a single, small seamless textured plane, and I want to make a large plane out of multiple of that texture. The array function is basically what I want to do, but it only goes in 1 direction which isnt ideal, and time consuming. Any help would be nice

Answer (score 4):

You can use **two** *Array Modifiers*. One for direction *X* and one for direction *Y*. The setup would look something like the following. Note how the values in the green boxes are different. This allows for the object (plane) to be arrayed in multiple directions. Just remember that *Array Modifiers* utilize local coordinates and you can negatize *(did I just invent a word there?)* values to have the object array in the opposite direction.

[image]

*How this modifier stack would look when applied to a cylinder (for clarity, because cylinders are easier to differentiate than planes):*

[image]

As a last note, you can use a *Vector > Mapping* node to tile textures on a single plane. See David's answer on [How to Make a image repeat in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21175/how-to-make-a-image-repeat-in-cycles).

Comment: @bexben If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. It would help me greatly, and make me very happy!

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative if I understand correctly what you want to do, without modifiers, is to *bake* your texture and apply it to a single large plane. Once your texture is baked, you will have the ability to add any amount of repetition you want just as an image texture. This is a simple example (in cycles, I don't know which engine you're using), using a small texture and a mapping node, it is repeated freely across a plane of any given size. This is the node setup and result:[image]

[image]

If you are unfamiliar with texture baking, the manual has more information [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html) and [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/baking.html) for cycles specifically.

Comment: This doesn't answer the op's question.

Comment: @ShadyPuck  the question asked 'how to make a large plane out of *multiple* of a texture'. The simplest way is bake the texture, scale the plane, and manipulate the texture coordinates to get the results desired. It is not necessary to use a modifier to do that.

Comment: Perhaps, but _array_ was mentioned.

Comment: @ShadyPuck the fact that array was mentioned doesn't make that necessary to use. More than that, the question is about achieving arraying *texture* which can be obtained not only with one way and nearly any problem can have multiple solutions. It's very good to investigate questions and possible solutions from larger point of view.